# EndCurrentEdit Not Working Properly When Changing Text Box Text Through Code

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding, controls

I have a few text boxes that are bound to a data table, e.g.:

```
With control.Item_Full_Description
    .DataBindings.Add("Text", mdtItemMstr, "Item_Full_Description", True)
End With
```

When I change the value of the text box text through the code is is not being pushed back to the database properly. If I call:

```
Me.BindingContext(_mdtItemMstr).EndCurrentEdit()
```

immediately after the change of value in code it does get saved back properly, however if I wait until the user actually clicks save (after making many more edits) to call `EndCurrentEdit` it does not save back. The problem with this approach is calling it after each change in code so many times causes conflicts.

Is there an obvious issue with this approach that could explain why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are binding your TextBox to a property on an underlying data source (mdtItemMstr.Item_Full_Description in your case), why don't you write to that property instead of writing to the TextBox ?

When I deal with bound controls, I always manipulate the underlying data, never the control directly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok I guess this doesn't answer my question but it is certainly an acceptable work around that is very easy. Thank you.

Comment: Well, really, when working with bound controls, my opinion is that you should never manipulate the control's value directly, but only the underlying datasource, letting data binding do its job :-)